# Retrieving Device Information React-Native iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

Hey I am trying to get device information from an iPad. I have tried using https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info but after I do pod install it completely break my solution. Id like to be able to at least get the device's name. How can I go about this without using an NPM module or does anyone know of one that works that doest have to pull in extra dependencies?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a library that uses native code to extract device-related information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done easily using [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios), no libraries or dependencies required.

**Synchronous version**

in your JS:

```
import { NativeModules} from "react-native"

const DeviceInfo = NativeModules.DeviceInfo;

const deviceName = DeviceInfo.getName();
```

in iOS:
RCTDeviceInfo.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCTDeviceInfo : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

RCTDeviceInfo.m

```
#import "RCTDeviceInfo.h"

@implementation RCTDeviceInfo

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(DeviceInfo);

RCT_EXPORT_BLOCKING_SYNCHRONOUS_METHOD(getName) {
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
}

@end
```

**Asynchronous version**

in your JS:

```
import { NativeModules} from "react-native"

const DeviceInfo = NativeModules.DeviceInfo;

DeviceInfo.getName().then(deviceName => {
  console.log("Current Device: "+deviceName);
}
```

in iOS:
RCTDeviceInfo.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCTDeviceInfo : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

RCTDeviceInfo.m

```
#import "RCTDeviceInfo.h"

@implementation RCTDeviceInfo

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(DeviceInfo);

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getName
              getName_resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
              getName_rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    resolve([[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah awesome this makes sense but when I go to try this in the app I get this error: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in chrome. Consider providing alternative methods to expose this method in debug mode, e.g by exposing constants ahead-of-time." Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You can't use a synchronous method in a native module if you also want to use the chrome debugger. I'll add another version that is asynchronous that won't crash the debugger

Comment: I can find no references to RCTDataLogger.h anywhere in my project or the React library source.  Does React have that class?

Comment: @AkinWilliams Sorry, that was a typo on my part. It should have been `#import "RCTDeviceInfo.h"`