# I would like to call Object-C method in react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to call Object-C methods in react-native. One specific reason I would like to do it to write time stamp on photos read from gallery. One of the method I would like to call is CGRectMake.

Any help would appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the same question, but it is the same answer, so i'll repost my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844549/retrieving-device-information-react-native-ios)

This can be done using [Native Modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios)

**Synchronous version**

in your JS:

```
import { NativeModules} from "react-native"

const DeviceInfo = NativeModules.DeviceInfo;

const deviceName = DeviceInfo.getName();
```

in iOS:
RCTDeviceInfo.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCTDeviceInfo : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

RCTDeviceInfo.m

```
#import "RCTDataLogger.h"

@implementation RCTDeviceInfo

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(DeviceInfo);

RCT_EXPORT_BLOCKING_SYNCHRONOUS_METHOD(getName) {
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
}

@end
```

**Asynchronous version**

in your JS:

```
import { NativeModules} from "react-native"

const DeviceInfo = NativeModules.DeviceInfo;

DeviceInfo.getName().then(deviceName => {
  console.log("Current Device: "+deviceName);
}
```

in iOS:
RCTDeviceInfo.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCTDeviceInfo : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

RCTDeviceInfo.m

```
#import "RCTDataLogger.h"

@implementation RCTDeviceInfo

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(DeviceInfo);

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getName
              getName_resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
              getName_rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    resolve([[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
}

@end
```